# Infrequent error appearing in spring application running under a JBoss AS 7.0.2

Tags: java, spring, apache, jboss

I've been experiencing an odd issue with an application written with the Spring Framework, running under a JBoss AS 7.0.2 server with an Apache+Siteminder frontend.

```
13:43:22,053 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (ajp--141.231.2.111-8009-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bosh/service/al28/atun/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'BoshServlet'
```

The error appears every now and then(it would seem that it's always the same URI, but I'm not 100% sure), resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error for the user currently using the application. Restarting both the application server and the httpd server makes it go away.

Any ideas?

Regards,

David

Comment: Upgrade JBoss to something more recent? You're running an alpha version of an alpha version. Research how to compile JBoss 7.2 yourself and try that to see if it is more stable.

Comment: That is an option, I'm currently migrating a couple of projects to JBoss EAP 6.2 .. but I would really like to figure out if this is due to some error in the developers code or if it's related to some bug in the JBoss AS 7.0.2.

Comment: So step one: see if the problem goes away on more stable server software. If not, then its likely a problem in the code or configuration and you'll need to start digging which might be a grueling and lengthy process.